# Most efficient way to dynamically make a segue in Obj-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am writing a segue for my app. Basically this segue should be called when an accessory in `UITableViewCell` is pressed.

Before writing it I'm planning how to handle it.

First method: Make a view, add labels, set identifier, call segue with `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath`, load view with identifier, access (somehow, not sure) the labels inside the view, change them with the appropriate content, display.

Second method: Make a nib, load nib somehow and make segue, access labels and change stuff appropriately, display.

I am not sure which method is best and what do I need to do to access the labels if I am using an identifier to load the view with the segue.

Suggestions?

Comment: Please provide more details about what do you want to achieve. If you working with storyboard and using system accessory view you can easy define segue via "Accessory Action".  If you want to call segue from code - use  UITableView Delegate func tableView tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: and launch segue you want from there (by id). If instead of accessory view, you want to define custom button, you can use define closure  in your cell, assign it while creating cell and use it.

Comment: Hey Michael that's exactly what I written on my post. I know what to do although I am not sure how to display dynamic content in something (that is not a xib) that is loaded with an identifier.

Comment: You mean you don't know how display content of the cells in table view, when content is dynamic?

Comment: No, I know how to do that. The thing is, when I display the segueView with the dynamic segue, how can I display dynamic content inside the segueView?

Comment: Tou mean how to make view presented by segue to know, what object to present?

Comment: Yes kind of. I want to access the labels inside the view presented by the segue to change them and display the content that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That greatly depends on the how you handling accessory view and triggering segue. The problem is that you had to trigger segue in on place, and actually provide information to the view in other. So you have to establish additional variable like `@property NSIndexPath *selectedAccessoryIndex;`.

Then update it accordingly, like

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    self.selectedAccessoryIndex = indexPath;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue" sender:nil];

}
```

And proceed it further while preparing for segue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    ((ViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).selectedString = self.array[self.accessoryIndex.row];
}
```

Mind that on this place destination view controller not loaded yet, so you can't access any outlet just now. Surely you can for it to load by calling `[segue.destinationViewController view];` But it is not recommended. Better to provide object to display (better weak). And then update outlets  in it's `viewDidLoad`